# How can I show all active leases of a Virtualbox DHCP server?

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp

I'm trying to debug an issue and trying to figure out if a particular Machine of mine even has an IP. How can I show all the leases of a Virtualbox DHCP server? The reason I can't just log into the guest is, that it's a Vulnhub VM. Finding out a way to log into the machine is the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: You can always go into the guest and issue an ipconfig to find out if it has a lease or not. Otherwise it should show up in the network tab in the network manager of Virtual  Box

Comment: @LPChip I should have mentioned that, I edited my original question.

Comment: Are you hosting this Vulnhub VM yourself or is it hosted elsewhere and are you trying to break in?

Comment: @LPChip I'm hosting it myself

Answer (score 6):

**On Linux :**

```
cat $HOME/Library/VirtualBox/NatNetwork-Dhcpd.leases
```

**On Windows :**

```
%userprofile%\\.VirtualBox\HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter-Dhcpd.leases
```

This is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Leases version="1.0">
...
  <Lease mac="08:00:27:45:fb:92" network="0.0.0.0" state="acked">
    <Address value="10.0.2.15"/>
    <Time issued="1594735097" expiration="600"/>
  </Lease>
...
</Leases>
```

You can find the mac from vm with `vboxmanage showvminfo smp318 | grep MAC`

You can list running VM with `vboxmanage list runningvms`

Answer (score 1):

On Debian systems:

```
cat ~/.config/VirtualBox/(your network name).leases
```

You can
`ls ~/.config/VirtualBox | grep ".leases"`
to see all of the DHCP leases of all networks created.